# Cutting beam corners

Tags: cutting, skirting

I have a wardrobe in the room I use as a little office. The wardrobe is built in and I'm planning to make a frame with beams to fit half of the wardrobe as shelves.

If you note the pic below, the inside wall of the wardrobe has the skirting board. I don't want to make holes inside the wardrobe, so I want to build the frame in a way that just fits inside so the horizontal beams will hold the vertical ones just using pressure.

So,

what is the best way and tool to cut the beam so it can fit the skirting board nicely?

Can I use the same tool/procedure to cut gaps so the vertical beans can fit in the horizontal ones?

I have a few tools in the garage like, circular saw, plunger router, drill and a dremel with a dremel router table.

Sorry if I haven't been clear enough.

Thanks.

[image: Bean and inside wall]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "bean" and "beans" ? Do you really mean "beam" ? I would have edited the question to change it to "beam" but I was just unsure enough that I thought I should get your intent.

Comment: @michael yes, you're right. Sorry, I didn't notice the mistake. :)

Comment: Beams are horizontal, posts are vertical; so I'm dubious that we are looking at a beam, here.

Comment: I want to get this piece of wood from the photo and find a way to put at the corner of the wardrobe but before I want to cut a little gap where the skirting board can fit nicely.